# Ubuntu 12.04 on Dell Mini 9: direct me to screen aspect ratio directions?

Tags: 12.04, installation, display, resolution

Can someone direct me to an existing discussion, if there is one, about how to install the right aspect ratio or screen resolution on my Dell Mini 9 now that I have Ubuntu 12.04? All the discussions I see are for other hardware. I am not so surefooted with terminal commands in general, though I was able to install the OS, so I am not terrible either. But what I have found is that if it's not for my machine, it won't work. The only option I have now is 800x600. I don't so much care about the resolution sharpness as the aspect ratio, which is too wide (that is, everything looks wide).
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should install the drivers for your GPU, which is Intel Integrated(?)
Type this into terminal:

```
    sudo su
    apt-get update
    apt-get upgrade
    apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Then you should be able to set the resolution in Settings > Displays